# Link to multiple versions of a library?

Tags: c++, opencv, linker, ros

I'm developing some apps in ROS (Robot Operating System), and am running into a problem with the linking stage.

When building an app in ROS, it links with OpenCV 2.4.9. The problem is that I have a personal library of functions, which we shall call MyLibrary that links with OpenCV 3.1.

Is it possible to create a ROS app that links with OpenCV 2.4.9 *and* MyLibrary (which links against OpenCV 3.1)?

All of this build environment is under my control except the version of ROS we are using. I cannot upgrade ROS (at least now) to a version that utilizes OpenCV 3.1. Is there anything I can do here?

My only thought is to configure MyLibrary so that it supports OpenCV 2.4.9 *and* OpenCV 3.1? This way I would just build MyLibrary for the ROS apps with the same version ROS is using, and there should be no conflicts. This is kind of a pain in the ass though... Is there something else that can be done with the build structure to support this?

Comment: Is it possible/allowed in your environment to link statically to OpenCV?

Comment: I'm not a true software engineer, so I only understand static/shared linking rather superficially. However, I should be able to setup static linking with MyLibrary, I'm a bit uncertain if this would be possible with the ROS portion though.

Comment: Sorry, mean to say... how would this help? Assuming it was possible, would that solve the problem?

Comment: Static linking basically copies all the library code into your project (i.e. MyLibrary), making it totally self containing but with a fixed version of the linked library. Dynamic linking just includes some "load the recent version of the library and call the functions there" code in your project. I have no experience with ROS or OpenCV, but it might solve your problem.

Comment: Make `MyLibrary` work with OpenCV 2.4.9. Anything else will be a headache at the best, even more so if your knowledge is limited.

Comment: Dan is right. There's a second option, however. If your code is a node, you could try to either remove/replace the dependency that pulls in OpenCV 2.4 (e.g. if you use cv_bridge, remove it) or rebuild it locally with OpenCV 3.1 (note that this may require patching and may start in a chain-reaction where you would have to migrate other packages ... may not be possible to take it to the end).

Comment: Thank you everyone. I was able to get it to work following http://answers.ros.org/question/214043/use-ros-indigo-opencv3-alongside-248/ which is what @dseifert was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

The following post http://answers.ros.org/question/214043/use-ros-indigo-opencv3-alongside-248/ shows how to do this.